# Svn switch from trunk to branch

Tags: svn, branch, trunk

I am in the root folder of an SVN-hosted project's `trunk` and am exploring setting up two branches.

One branch will be a "snapshot" of the project at the current (stable) revision, and a second branch will be one I'll work on to apply some new code, test, and then upgrade the trunk to a new version.

My goal is to keep the snapshot as insurance and a quick way to get an older, stable version of our project. The second branch, once we apply fresh code and the tests pass, will be merged back into the trunk, which we offer to the public.

To set up the snapshot, I copied our `trunk` to a branch called `v1p2p3`:

```
$ svn cp https://www.example.com/svn/trunk \ 
         https://www.example.com/svn/branches/v1p2p3 \
         -m "Branching from root trunk to v1p2p3 at r1114"
```

So far, so good:

```
Committed revision 1115.
```

What I would like to do is switch my local repository copy to this branch, to make sure that things worked, but I get an error message:

```
$ svn switch --relocate https://www.example.com/svn/trunk \
                        https://www.example.com/svn/branches/v1p2p3
```

The error message is:

```
svn: E155024: Invalid relocation destination: 
              'https://www.example.com/svn/branches/v1p2p3' 
              (does not point to target)
```

What am I doing wrong?

(If this doesn't work, I suspect I can't get to starting on the more ambitious second branch. I'm looking for a way to do this that won't damage the existing project layout. Thanks for your advice, and apologies if this is a dumb question.)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You don't need to `--relocate` since the branch is within the same repository URL. Just do:

```
svn switch https://www.example.com/svn/branches/v1p2p3
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. I assume any changes after switching to this URL will leave the `trunk` alone, correct?

Comment: Yup. Further commits while your WC is pointed to the branch will only commit to that branch. You can check where the commits will go using `svn info`

Answer (score 43):

- Short version of (correct) tzaman answer will be (for fresh SVN)

  ```
  svn switch ^/branches/v1p2p3
  ```
- `--relocate` switch is deprecated anyway, *when it needed* you'll have to use `svn relocate` command
- Instead of creating snapshot-branch (ReadOnly) you can use tags (conventional RO labels for history)

On Windows, the caret character (`^`) must be escaped:

```
svn switch ^^/branches/v1p2p3
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting tags: "snapshot as insurance and a quick way to get an older, stable version" sounds like the classical use case for tags, which are usually created as part of the release process.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I wanted to `check out` a `new branch` that has cut recently
but it's it big in size and I want to save time and internet bandwidth, as I'm in a slow metered network

so I `copped the previous branch` that I already checked in

I went to the working directory, and from svn info, I can see it's on the previous branch I did the following command (you can find this command from `svn switch --help`)

```
svn switch ^/branches/newBranchName
```

go check `svn info` again you can see it is becoming the newBranchName go ahead and `svn up`

and this how I got the new branch easily, quickly with minimum data transmitting over the internet

hope sharing my case helps and speeds up your work